Length of an inline array
A new feature in c# 12 are inline arrays like
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(10)]
public struct Buffer
{
    private object element;
}

as described here.
If I define an instance of such array like
Buffer a = new();

I would expect that something like a.Size or a.Length is defined as a property or method, but it is not.
I found this way to get the length of the buffer: ((ReadOnlySpan<double>)a).Length. Is there a more elegant way?

you can try a[..].Length

[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(Buffer.Length)]
public struct Buffer
{
    private object element;

    public const int Length = 10;  // Define the length as a constant
}

Buffer a = new();
var length = Buffer.Length;

Or
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(Buffer.length)]
public struct Buffer
{
    private object element;

    private const int length = 10;  // Define the length as a constant
    public int Length => length;
}

Buffer a = new();
var length = a.Length;

In this example, the Length property is defined directly in the struct, providing a more intuitive way to access the buffer's length. This property simply returns the constant size of the inline array. However, keep in mind that this approach requires you to manually synchronize the Length property value with the actual size defined in the InlineArray attribute.
This is not as dynamic as getting the length from a ReadOnlySpan, which adapts to the actual type and size of the buffer, but it provides a clean and straightforward interface for accessing the length.

I suggest defining as a constant: public const int Length = 10; which you can use in the attribute: [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(Buffer.Length)]

I would like to make Dmitry's modification of Alberto's answer the accepted one. Could one of you create this version as a new answer or modify the existing one?

@MarkusParker updated the code from the OP to match the  request.


I would expect that something like a.Size or a.Length is defined as a property or method, but it is not.

Unfortunately at the moment there is nothing out of the box. As is written in this discussion in the csharplang:

InlineArray is intended to be the hidden backing storage, that is not used directly. Instead, you can just wrap it freely as a span, and then get all the niceties of that higher level abstraction.

And

Honestly the only answer here should be to just cast it to a Span<T> and then get the Length. It jumps through a few hoops but at least the runtime seems perfectly capable of folding everything and just returning the constant value.

Basically what you have already discovered:
Buffer a = new();
Console.WriteLine(((Span<object>)a).Length);

Using the range operator ([..], which is a bit more esoteric looking, but much shorter) results in the same IL code generated:
Console.WriteLine(a[..].Length);

// decompiled generated code
Console.WriteLine(<PrivateImplementationDetails>.InlineArrayAsSpan<Buffer, object>(ref buffer, 10).Length);

demo @sharplab.io
As an option you can write a source generator which will generate some extension methods for all the inline arrays.
P.S.
The "but at least the runtime seems perfectly capable of folding everything and just returning the constant value" - claim seems to be  wrong based on JIT ASM produced by the sharplab.io.

"at least the runtime seems perfectly capable of folding everything and just returning the constant value" doesn't seem to be backed up by the JIT ASM in sharplab

@Charlieface yes, got that feeling too looking at it but had not time to investigate more. Will update the answer, thank you.

From the Inline Array documentation:

Language will provide a type-safe/ref-safe way for accessing elements of inline array types. The access will be span based.

Where the next section covers how to obtain the span.
That is, you are not expected to directly access the variable's size or Length members. Instead, you get a Span and use that to manipulate the array. Also, since arrays are fixed size, you should already know the .Length based on the attribute argument provided when declaring the struct.

since arrays are fixed size, you should already know the .Length Inline arrays are just regular structs, which means that they can implement interfaces. You can constrain a generic method against an interface and avoid boxing. Given void Foo<T>(T value) where T : struct, IFoo, value will not be boxed. Two arbitrary inline arrays of different sizes could both implement a common interface and be operated on via such a constrained generic method, without boxing, in which case, you would not already know the .Length of the generic argument. (/devil's advocate)

As a practical use case, you might have inline arrays such as Buffer8<T>, Buffer16<T>, and Buffer32<T>. If these all implement a common interface, IBuffer<T>, which provides a Length property, a constrained generic method could then operate on a buffer of any of these sizes. The Length property would be accessible, again, without boxing, so while the use case may be niche, there are conceivable practical uses.

In response to this thread and others like it across the web, I have written a source generator that can produce a number of array-like and collection-like features for inline arrays: Monkeymoto.InlineCollections.
As of this answer, this project is still under active development, with a NuGet package planned at some point in the future.
For a simple Length property, you could do something such as:
using Monkeymoto.InlineCollections;

[InlineCollection(InlineCollectionOptions.LengthProperty, Length = 8)]
public partial struct Buffer8<T>
{
    private T element0;
}

var buffer = new Buffer8<int>();
Console.WriteLine($"Length: {buffer.Length}");

Some other features that can be included are (all are opt-in):

Collection expression support (generates a class for CollectionBuilderAttribute)
Explicit conversion operators to and from T[]
Array/span-like methods, such as Clear() and Fill(T)
List-like methods, such as Contains(T) and IndexOf(T)
Interface implementations such as ICollection, ICollection<T>, IList, IList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, and IReadOnlyList<T>
A public ref struct Enumerator type for non-boxing enumerators (inline arrays include loop-based enumeration out-of-the-box; this allows control over the enumerator without boxing to IEnumerator or IEnumerator<T>).

Additionally, this adds a code analyzer for collection expressions that can help detect at compile-time if your collection expression is too large for the target type:
[InlineCollection(InlineCollectionOptions.Everything, Length = 4)]
public partial struct Buffer4<T>
{
    private T element0;
}

Buffer4<int> buffer = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // no diagnostic
int[] array = (int[])buffer; // explicit array conversion
//buffer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // error: collection expression is too large!
//buffer = [array[0], 2, 3, 4, 5]; // error: collection expression is too large!
buffer = [..array, ..array[0..1], 3, 4, 5]; // warning: collection expression may be too large after expansion
//buffer = [..array, ..array[0..1], 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; // error: collection expression is too large!

